# How to get value of jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this jquery plugin. I want to get selected time value and save it to some input on page. How can I achieve this ?

Plugin and code here:

http://jsfiddle.net/weareoutman/YkvK9/

```
var input = $('#input-a');
input.clockpicker({
    autoclose: true
});

// Manual operations
$('#button-a').click(function(e){
    // Have to stop propagation here
    e.stopPropagation();
    input.clockpicker('show')
            .clockpicker('toggleView', 'minutes');
});
$('#button-b').click(function(e){
    // Have to stop propagation here
    e.stopPropagation();
    input.clockpicker('show')
            .clockpicker('toggleView', 'hours');
});
```

Comment: save it how? like on submitting a form or use it for some other part of the current page?

Comment: Right now, after I'm choosing a time, value is saved to "input-a". But I want it to be saved to another id for example to #new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it using `.val()`:

```
 $('#input-a').val();
```

To update input on Change:

```
$('.container').clockpicker().find('input').change(function(){
  $('#new').val(this.value);
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YkvK9/6/)**

Comment: This is not what exactly I want. I need to get value, before it's written to input. I need value of choosen options, straight from timepicker, not from input to input.

Comment: @user1876234: how is that different from selected value.why do you want to make things complicated.

Comment: Right now, after I'm choosing a time, value is saved to "input-a". But I want it to be saved to another id for example to #new.

Comment: @user1876234: check the fiddle . you can set the input value on change event of input.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#input-a').val();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YkvK9/4/

see demo

Comment: Right now, after I'm choosing a time, value is saved to "input-a". But I want it to be saved to another id for example to #new.

Comment: so what change the id as per your requirement